# Android Programming with Camera framework API

Tags: android, multithreading, camera

New to android programming, writing an application that continuously streams image from camera and do some operation on and post the result on screen. My camera class is separate from the main activity class. I have a queue for captured images, two threads that reads and writes to the queue. I am having problems possibly with the initializations. I am not sure if I am using the CameraPreview correctly.

Here is my code.

```
public class Goggle extends Activity{

    ImageQueue imageQueue = new ImageQueue();
    ImageCapture capture;

    private ThreadProcess thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        ...... 

        capture  = new ImageCapture(this,imageQueue);
        capture.start();

        thread = new ThreadProcess();
        thread.start();

    }    

    private class ThreadProcess extends Thread {
    ...
    }
}

public class ImageCapture extends Thread implements Camera.PreviewCallback{
    private ImageQueue imageQueue;
    private ImageUInt8 image;

    private Activity   parent; 

    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Camera        mCamera;

    public ImageCapture (Activity parnt, ImageQueue queue) {
        this.parent = parnt;
        this.imageQueue = queue;
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(parent,this,true);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        setUpAndConfigureCamera();
    }

    /**
     * Called each time a new image arrives in the data stream.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {

        // convert from NV21 format into gray scale
        synchronized (lockImage) {
            ConvertNV21.nv21ToGray(bytes,image.width,image.height,image);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lockImage) {
                ImageData imageData = new ImageData(image);
                imageQueue.pushImage(imageData);
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your problem is? Human beings will not read your code just to understand the question. Please post the logs if they contain any relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a camera thread (ImageCapture class) which uses Goggle as parent activity. I also have a imagequeue class to store the captured images. My problem is that I cannot read the image. When debugging I can see that the camera seems to be opened. Below are the logs.

Comment: Was going to refer you to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/553637/Real-Time-Computer-Vision-on-Android-using-BoofCV  but it looks like some of this code came from there.  Have you tried just using that example verbatim then slightly modifying it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes part of the code is from there. Their code works fine. I wanted to remove the camera to a separate thread (in the future I will have each sensor on a separate thread feeding their own queues). I do not see why creating a separate class with its own function does not work.